# Appealing to reopen a question: programmatically convert lat/long to timezone

Tags: support, closed-questions, reopen-closed

The following question has been closed by George Stocker:

[Timezone lookup from latitude longitude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41504/timezone-lookup-from-latitude-longitude)

...on the grounds that it's off topic, but I don't see how it's off topic. It's a question about programming, a question that received a lot of interest while it was open, and a question that a lot of programmers including me need answered.  I couldn't see any comment from George about why he considers it off topic.  Can a moderator re-open it or can someone help me understand why it's off topic?

Comment: Request for off site resources are closed now.  The lock is because it predates this rule and the answers might be useful.

Comment: It's locked because it probably is useful, despite being off topic

Comment: Can you explain why the existing answers are not good enough?

Comment: [Refer to #5](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: You should ask for the dead answer, the almost-answer and the duplicate answers to be deleted at least, instead

Comment: The wording for 'off topic' is sub-optimal, but the text underneath the bold 'off topic' accurately displays why the question is not a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

The question is [off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) under the following rule

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

However it has been locked rather than closed because, despite being off topic, it was considered to be useful.

Future recommendation questions may find a home on   a new beta site; [software recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).  **But** only [highly specific recommendation questions are accepted there](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: Okay, I can understand the reasoning now.  However, this rule leaves me feeling a bit 'stuck': so much of software development involves finding the right tools, and we're constantly being told not to reinvent the wheel.  I don't see opinionated answers as necessarily a bad thing, as long as all the relevant offerings get a mention. Has this issue been discussed on Meta ad nauseum? Because if there was a case for applying the rule flexibly, I think this would be such a case.

Comment: @Tim You may be interested in a new beta site; [software recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) which I probably should have mentioned earlier.  **But** only highly specific recommendation questions are accepted there.

Comment: If you can put a link to the beta site in that closed question then that should solve the problem. I copied the question to here:  https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2714/timezone-lookup-from-latitude-longitude/2715#2715

Comment: I would actually prefer if all the resources we need could be kept in one place, i.e. StackOverflow. I don't see any problem with spirited debate except for reputation points inflation. If questions could be tagged "fanboy" by moderators, and if this would cap all point changes, then we might not need the software recommendations site.